# Is this a Disconnector beside MOVs?

Tags: surge-protection

[image: surgeprotector]

This is inside a power strip surge protector. What is that tubelike thing between the MOVs? Is it the disconnector (written "22IR UMI, 4A, 102 Celcius, 250V")? Can anyone show me images of a disconnector as I can't seem to find any in the net?

What threshold before the disconnector would totally disconnect? Because if there are small surges and the MOVs short a bit, would this be enough to activate the disconnector?

And equally important.. are all power strip surge protectors in the market require to have disconnectors? Or do other brands omit these? Without disconnectors, the MOVs can just burn up and cause a fire.

Comment: Could it be a thermal fuse?

Comment: By 'disconnector' do you mean "fuse", F4?

Comment: a disconnector is something that disconnects when the MOV element shorts.. so it won't burn.. the glass thing is a fuse (F4).. but I'm talking about the two white tubes (with red texts) besides the MOVs (F2).

Comment: Can anyone share any video of actual 110v surge protector with thermal fuse being intentionally plugged in to 220v, I want to see what would happen and if there would be a sound or smoke and I don't want to experiment on my own (I don't wanna waste $40).

Answer (score 1):

In the USA UL 3rd and 4th edition and ISO require all SPD devices to have both thermal disconnects as well as fast blow fuses.

The fuses protect against sudden overloads due to a powerful surge, such as a lightning strike.

The thermal fuse protects the SPD from over voltage which may cook the MOVs and be a fire hazard. The main fuse will not blow on an over voltage condition, as it is normally a 30 amp platinum fuse, so 20 amps of continuous current would cook the MOVs.

This also allows the SPD to be built inside a UL approved plastic enclosure, such as small residential units.

The goal is to have a safe shutdown of the SPD no matter what happens.

Comment: So F2 is the thermal fuse and F4 is the fast blow fuses?  Why is it called thermal disconnector or fuse.. isn't it it detects if the MOV is shorted then it shorted itself too.. what has thermal or temperature got to do with the functioning of F2?

Comment: You need to read my answer better. A thermal fuse opens up before the MOVs get so hot they melt the plastic case or short out, in which case the main fuse would open.

Comment: I see. So F2 are thermal fuse while F4 is fast blow fuse? Just to verify. What are other terms for thermal fuse.. as I can't seem to find any such items in google search.

Comment: I mean does the thermal fuse sense the temperature and disconnects from increased temperature? is it how thermal fuse work?

Comment: Look up thermal protection, thermal disconnect, TPMOV, which is a large 40mm MOV with a thermal disconnect built in. FERRAZ-Shawmut makes them.

Comment: Yes, that is how a thermal fuse or disconnect works.

Comment: I thought fuse only refers to something that disconnects when there is increased in current to a certain threshold. So thermal fuse doesn't sense current but temperature. I see. Anyway When you connect this 120v surge protector to a 240v outlet.. then I guess it won't cause fire anymore unlike products 15 years ago which doesn't have thermal fuses.

Comment: Correct. You got it now.

Comment: For those surge protectors made in china or other countries without UL marks.. I guess they don't have any thermal fuse?  I wonder how many percentage approx. of surge protectors worldwide still don't have thermal fuses. Any guess?

Comment: I am in bed on my cell phone. Please ask that as a new question. Do not buy SPD without UL and ISO labels.

Comment: Ok.. but if the MOV is already burning, even if the thermal disconnects no longer supply current.. it won't stop the burning.. I wonder if a thermal disconnect is so sensitive it can exactly sense 70 degrees (or so) increase in temperature? So a thermal disconnect is rated by temperature like normal fuses by current?

Comment: One last comment. The thermal fuse is supposed to open before any burning happens. No smoke or fire is allowed! That is UL and ISO regulations. Get your mind away from the way old SPD units behaved.